# Flurry -retransmitNotSentBlocks Crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, flurry-analytics

Recently came across this issue with the Flurry SDK. After restarting an app quickly a few times it would begin to Crash at launch, disabling Flurry fixed the issue temporarily. The problematic method seems to be `[FlurryDataSender retransmitNotSentBlocks]` trying to insert a nil object into an array. Any ideas?

[image: navigator]

[image: console]

Comment: Actually it wasn't resolved in 6.4.0 for me.

Comment: Some news. Does not resolved in 6.5.0. Even more news: the 6.5.0 is currently not available on official SDK downloading page (they offer only 6.4.0), although it was available in 20-s of may 2015.

Comment: ...Gettin rid of the shitty Flurry SDK prefering Google Analytics.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This issue is resolved in iOS SDK v6.4.0

Comment: I hope you guys realize how many problems your clients had been experiencing until you fixed it, few weeks later.

Comment: NO IT IS NOT FIXED in 6.4.0

Comment: We are still getting crashes with 6.4.0: `Thread : Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x21b44fef __exceptionPreprocess + 126
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x30092c8b objc_exception_throw + 38
2  CoreFoundation                 0x21a5eefb -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:] + 638
3  walletkeeper                   0x003dfcfd -[FlurryDataSender retransmitNotSentBlocks]`

Comment: Hi. Is it fixed in th v6.5.0 release ? Can we someway disable analytics from the server ?

Comment: @hsafarya no, it is not fixed in 6.5.0

Answer (score 1):

We apologize for the inconvenience this issue has caused all of you. An sdk to address this crash is expected on or around 6/26/15.

SDK 6.5 was intended to address a cookie issue that we later determined was better solved on the server side. v6.4 and v6.5 are functionally equivalent.

Comment: It is 6/29/15 now but still no new SDK. My app release is under hold due to this - when will you actually release?

Comment: The new version was released on 6/26 and should be available for download under Manage -> App Info from the Application screen.

Comment: Please could you bump the version in your podspec to give us access to 6.6.

Comment: We aren't the publisher of this: https://cocoapods.org/?q=flurry I am working with the SDK team to get our's published. In the meantime please download the SDK from Manage -> App Info on the application screen.

Comment: Thanks, I think you guys should take ownership of this pod http://blog.cocoapods.org/Claim-Your-Pods/

Comment: we use sdk 6.5.0 and there are still crashs. It appears to be one of the top crash reason in our crash log. Please fix it, we are frustrating here

Comment: @jAckOdE - please update to v6.7 found under Manage -> App Info on the application screen

Comment: @FlurrySupport any updates about an official pod? Pretty please?

Comment: Please go here and upvote the feature request Peter: https://yahoo.uservoice.com/forums/309376

Answer (score 0):

for us, this was resolved in v6.5.0 
we had a reproducible crash in an iphone 5c in v6.4.0 which was fixed when we upgraded the sdk.